# Launch android activity from key press

Tags: android, android-activity, keypress, launch

Is there any way to get an activity to launch from another application or the home screen when a key is pressed? I'm working with Android 4.l.1, and the button in question is registered on the device as the L2 button.

Answer (score 0):

Which activity you want to launch? You can handle the click event for the button to start an activity. Please provide more details